# ipad ios 5 UI strange behaviour

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm creating an iphone application and it has header and footer menus.after launch the application footer and header menu animation starts.I have tested on iphone 4 & 5 (ios 5,6) and works fine.
on ipad(ios 5x) footer menu displays half hidden but ipad os 6x works fine.is this an issue with iOS? or do I have to change the animation only for ipad ios5x?

I use 2 different view controllers for each screen size

animation code

```
-(void)animateDisplayObject:(NSMutableArray *)topOjects bottom:(NSMutableArray *)bottomObjects{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

    if(_hidden){
        for(UIButton *obj in topOjects){
            [obj setFrame:CGRectMake(obj.frame.origin.x, obj.frame.origin.y-65, obj.frame.size.width, obj.frame.size.height)];
        }
        for(UIButton *obj in bottomObjects){
            [obj setFrame:CGRectMake(obj.frame.origin.x, obj.frame.origin.y+125, obj.frame.size.width, obj.frame.size.height)];
        }
        _hidden = false;
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

please help.

Comment: do place some piece of code here.........

Comment: I added the code I use to display buttons.but this works fine excepting ipad 5x.

Comment: Problem is in your hardcoded value in the frame. You will never get a perfect view on different ios with hardcode. So set the autoLayout property of your view, it will work fine for every ios...

Comment: thanks for the comment.I'm using two different viewControllers for different screen sizes.enabling autolayout makes buttons stretched.why?

Comment: +1 for @PrateekPrem . Unless no other choice, don't hardcode sizes and prefer using autolayout.

Comment: Are you using Image for your button? So In that case you need separate images of button for different ios. and set the image programtically.

Comment: yes I'm using images for buttons.separate images for different ios?I dont understand.do you mean separate images for each screen sizes?